# sql, exists or count

Tags: sql-server-2008, count, exists

I have a table and want to check if there exists any record which satisfies some simple condition.
I'd like to know which will work faster:

`if (select count(*) from ... where ...) > 0`

or

`if exists (select top (1) from ... where ...)` .

Comment: exists returns result as soon as it finds record with matching where-clause while count needs to scan whole table to determine count. So exists is faster

Comment: rt2800, write that as an answer and I'll accept it )))

Comment: http://sqlblog.com/blogs/andrew_kelly/archive/2007/12/15/exists-vs-count-the-battle-never-ends.aspx

Comment: ken2k, this was really helpful, thank's a lot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

exists returns result as soon as it finds record with matching where-clause while count needs to scan whole table to determine count. So exists is faster

Answer (score 3):

```
if exists (select 1 from ... where ...)
```

(assuming you have index on the `where` column...)